# Google Search results for flights

Tags: google-search

Google introduced a new way to display flight results in its search. Example:

[image]

However, I'm not seeing the results this way... I just see the "hyperlinks" text results (and Google Ads).
What am I doing wrong? What setting should I enable? Do I need a Google+ account?

Comment: Generally they roll features out rather than turning them on for everyone all at once. Are you in the U.S.? Are you using google.com? What's a sample search term you're using? (It's possible that Google isn't recognizing it as a flight number.)

Comment: I'm not in the US, but I'm using Google.com. My colleagues who are just next to me, are able to see the above image. I'm the only one who isn't. The query I'm using (and that was used to take the screenshot above) is "delta 1169".

Comment: Are they logged in to Google and you're not, or vice versa? If you're all logged in then it would seem the feature hasn't been rolled out to your account yet.

Comment: No, just discovered the problem. Google is not displaying in English for me (but it was for them). The above flight presentation only appears if your Google preferences show in English

Comment: Ah. Yes that would make sense. Their new features almost always come out in English first. I'm sure they'll roll it out for other languages later. You should post that as the answer; I'm sure you're not the only person who would be wondering about that.

Answer (score 2):

I had to change my **Primary language** to **English**, in my Google Account settings.
Not sure if this feature is available for other languages.